# Swift assertion failing

Tags: swift, runtime-error, quicksort

My program fails compiling, can you help me out? It seems (from this and my previous attempts) that Swift doesn't like my usage of inout arguments.

Here's my code (it implements quicksort with logarithmic memory complexity by choosing into which part to recurse):

```
func sort<T: Comparable>(
  _ arr: inout [T],
  _ start: inout Int = 0,
  _ end: inout Int = 0)
{
  if end == 0 { end = arr.count }
  while start < end {
    var i = start
    let pivot = arr[i]
    for j in i + 1 ..< end
    {
      let t = arr[j]
      if t < pivot {
        arr[j] = arr[i]
        arr[i] = t
        i += 1
      }
    }
    if i > start {
      let bounds = [start, i, i, end]
      var j = 2 * i > start + end ? 2 : 0
      (start, end) = (bounds[j], bounds[j + 1])
      sort(&arr, &start, &end)
      j = (j + 2) % 4
      (start, end) = (bounds[j], bounds[j + 1])
    }
    else { start += 1 }
  }
}

var a = [3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5]
sort(&a)
print(a)
```

And here's the output:

```
Swift version 5.0.1 (swift-5.0.1-RELEASE)
 swiftc -o main main.swift
swift: /home/buildnode/jenkins/workspace/oss-swift-5.0-package-linux-ubuntu-18_04/swift/lib/AST/ASTContext.cpp:3186: swift::TupleTypeElt::TupleTypeElt(swift::Type, swift::Identifier, swift::ParameterTypeFlags): Assertion `!ty->is<InOutType>() && "caller did not pass a base type"' failed.
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: /usr/bin/swift -frontend -c -primary-file main.swift -target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -disable-objc-interop -color-diagnostics -module-name main -o /tmp/main-c3dd3d.o 
1.  While type-checking statement at [main.swift:32:1 - line:32:8] RangeText="sort(&a"
2.  While type-checking expression at [main.swift:32:1 - line:32:8] RangeText="sort(&a"
/usr/bin/swift[0x423d3b4]
/usr/bin/swift[0x423b13e]
/usr/bin/swift[0x423d572]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x12890)[0x7fbbee94b890]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0xc7)[0x7fbbecdaee97]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x141)[0x7fbbecdb0801]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x3039a)[0x7fbbecda039a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x30412)[0x7fbbecda0412]
/usr/bin/swift[0x1758aff]
/usr/bin/swift[0x1509882]
/usr/bin/swift[0x14f9942]
/usr/bin/swift[0x150d06a]
/usr/bin/swift[0x14fbbeb]
/usr/bin/swift[0x17d3117]
/usr/bin/swift[0x14f359b]
/usr/bin/swift[0x143c618]
/usr/bin/swift[0x143c162]
/usr/bin/swift[0x14d1c9d]
/usr/bin/swift[0x14d0e17]
/usr/bin/swift[0x14d0f22]
/usr/bin/swift[0x14f0647]
/usr/bin/swift[0xd3a10a]
/usr/bin/swift[0xd38eb0]
/usr/bin/swift[0xd38511]
/usr/bin/swift[0x4beb31]
/usr/bin/swift[0x4bd7c9]
/usr/bin/swift[0x46e630]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe7)[0x7fbbecd91b97]
/usr/bin/swift[0x46ca4a]
<unknown>:0: error: unable to execute command: Aborted
<unknown>:0: error: compile command failed due to signal 6 (use -v to see invocation)
compiler exit status 254
```

Comment: When I compile this on a Mac with Xcode, the compiler clearly objects to setting defaults on inout parameters. Remove the defaults and pass start and end at the top level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`inout` arguments can't have default values, as you need to provide an actual memory location for those arguments. So you'll need to create two `var`'s for those variables:

```swift
func sort<T: Comparable>(
  _ arr: inout [T],
  _ start: inout Int,
  _ end: inout Int)
{
   ...
}

var start = 0, end = 0
sort(&arr, &start, &end)
```

Now, if you want to be able to call the function in an easier manner, without forcing the callers to create two variables each time, and to make sure those variables are initialized with zero, you can add an overload to your `sort` function:

```swift
func sort<T: Comparable>(
  _ arr: inout [T],
  _ start: inout Int,
  _ end: inout Int)
{
    ...
}

func sort<T: Comparable>(_ arr: inout [T]) {
    var start = 0, end = 0
    sort(&arr, &start, &end)
}

var a = [3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5]
sort(&a)
print(a)
```

However, you could have an even nicer and more idiomatic call site, by extending `Array` (or even `Collection`) with your sort function:

```swift
extension Array where Element: Comparable {
    mutating func mySort() {
        var start = 0, end = 0
        Self.mySort(&self, &start, &end)
    }
    
    private static func mySort(
        _ arr: inout [Element],
        _ start: inout Int,
        _ end: inout Int)
    {
        ... same sorting logic
    }
}

var a = [3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5]
a.mySort() // instead of sort(&a)
print(a)
```